# Datatables passing array to render giving strange result

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have a datatables of authors with an image and I want to pass to items to a render area on my table:

```
{
          "targets":[3],
          "data": "['image','author']",
          "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return '<a href="images/authors/'+ data[0] + '" class="ilightbox" ><img src="images/authors/50/'+ data[0] +'"  /></a>';
          }
        },
```

Both items are fine in the database  and if I remove this render I get:

[image]

when I add in this render option and inspect it I get:

[image]

I have tried amending the data line to

```
"data": ['image','author'],
```

but I get exactly the same output.

Comment: What seems to be the problem? I'm guessing you're trying to get a lighbox to show when clicking on the Author name?

Comment: When you use `"targets":[3]`, that becomes the data used by the column renderer's `data` value - and the `"data": "['image','author']"` is ignored. So, `data[0]` is just the first letter in each string (from the column 3 contents). You can access all of the fields in each row using the `row` value in the renderer. It looks as if that is what you need, so you can grab the JPEG name. Exactly how you do this depends on whether the source data (JSON) was provided as an array of arrays, or an array of objects. You can print `row` to the console to see.